# C - Duplicate symbol if put include in header, but works fine if include in source file

Tags: c, include, header-files

I have a header file that contains an array of int

`primes.h`

```
#ifndef P_H
#define P_H
#include <inttypes.h>

uint64_t primes[] = {
    7,
    11,
};
#endif
```

in `lib.h` file:
`#include "primes.h"`

`lib.c` includes `lib.h`

in `main.c` file:
`#include "lib.h"`

Then it causes error: `duplicate symbol '_primes' in:`

But if i move `#include "primes.h"` into `lib.c`, it works fine.
Why putting include in source and header can make the difference?

Comment: See also [How do I use `extern` to share variables between source files?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1433387/15168).

Comment: Your `lib.c` probably also includes `lib.h`, correct?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler i know about extern, just curious about why including in source file makes it work.

Comment: Then you should read that link again. Using `extern` and where to place the definition is closely tied together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you include a file, the include is replaced with the file contents (and this continues until there are no more includes).

- If `main.c` and `lib.c` both include `lib.h`, then they both have separate copies of `lib.h` compiled in.
- If `lib.h` includes `primes.h`, then they both have their own separate copies of `primes.h` compiled in.
- If `primes.h` has an array defined, then they both have a copy of that array.
- And if they both have anything with the same name defined in both files, you get a duplicate definition error.

The best way to fix this is to only have 1 definition of the `primes` array with all of its values in a source file (e.g. `lib.c`), and you need to use the `extern` keyword in `primes.h` with no values to declare that one of your files contains the actual array (you can leave the size unspecified in this case).  Note that this use of the `extern` keyword is a sort of promise to the compiler that there is some file containing the actual array, and that's why you still need the actual array in a source file:

```
// primes.h
extern uint64_t primes[];

// lib.c
#include "primes.h"
uint64_t primes[] = {
    7,
    11,
};

// main.c
#include "primes.h"
```

Answer (score 2):

You are defining a variable in the h-file. This means that you can only include that h-file in one compilation unit, i.e. in one c-file. So when you include it in `lib.h` and in case `lib.h` is included in multiple c-files, your in trouble, i.e. multiple compilation units will define the array variable `primes`. That won't work.

**Rule:** Don't define variables in h-files. Always do it in c-files.

(note: there may be exceptions but this is the golden rule - stick to it unless you have a real good reason for putting variables in h-files)

See this answer for a how-to description: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1433387/4386427

Comment: Thank for the compilation unit, i know nothing about it. So is that wrong to do include `primes.h` in source file? I don't wanna use `extern` since i need to create `primes.c` to define variable in it.

Comment: @TomSawyer When a program is made from several c-files, each of these c-files are a "compilation unit". They are compiled one-by-one and later linked together to form the whole program. I don't understand why you are saying "I don't wanna use extern ..." ? That's the way to do it! Define the variable in a c-file and put the extern declaration in the h-file.